# IOS download data with JSON for a IPhone APP

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json, xcode

i try to download data from a webserver with json into my ios app.

That´s the json output

```
{
    "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":37,
        "params":{
            "wt":"json",
            "q":"title:ios"
        }
    },
    "response":{
        "numFound":348,
        "start":0,
        "docs":[
            {
                "edition":"2. ed.",
                "illustrated":"Not Illustrated",
                "id":"BSZ117259543",
                "author":"Raw, Charles",
                "title":"IOS /",
                "spelling":"Raw, Charles (DE-576)180904566 Do you sincerely want to be rich? span. IOS / Charles Raw; Bruce Page; Godfrey Hodgson 2. ed. SÃ£o Paulo : Ed. ExpressÃ£o e Cultura, 1972 XV, 496 S. Page, Bruce (DE-576)162468539 aut Hodgson, Godfrey (DE-576)161444822 aut",
                "last_indexed":"2012-09-02T01:11:38Z",
                "recordtype":"marc",
                "title_auth":"IOS /",
                "title_sort":"ios",
                "title_short":"IOS /",
                "fullrecord":"00985nam a22003372"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The Code of my project:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// 1 Schritt
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
//code executed in the background
// 2
//NSData* kivaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://api.kivaws.org/v1/loans/search.json?status=fundraising"]];

    NSData* kivaData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bib.flux-services.net/solr/biblio/select?q=title:ios&wt=json"]];

    //3

    NSDictionary* json = nil;
    if (kivaData) {
        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:kivaData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    }

    //4
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUIWithDictionary:json];
    });

});
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)updateUIWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)json {

@try {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ from %@",
                  json[@"docs"][0][@"title"],
                  json[@"docs"][0][@"edition"],
                  //json[@"loans"][0][@"loan_amount"],
                  //json[@"loans"][0][@"use"],
                  nil
                  ];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                               message:@"Could not parse the json feed."
                              delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil]show];
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
}
```

When I run the programm then the IPhone simulator could not display the data.

I haven´t any idea where´s the problem!?!

Have anybody a idea or a solution???

Comment: did you check your JSON response? Pass &error to JSON serialization it might be broken. Add NSLog("Response dictinary %@", json); to your -update method

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.

Comment: And **use the `error:` parm** of NSJSONSerialization!!

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Are you sure it's the JSON and not something else in your app? Please edit your question to provide the expected outcome and the actual outcome as `could not display the data` is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

First, exceptions are for programming errors. You don't catch exceptions. If you get exceptions, your program crashes, you find the reason, you fix the code. That's how it's done in Objective-C. People might thing you are a Java programmer.

Second, an NSLog of the dictionary you received would be useful. What you printed doesn't match your code.

Third, when you get JSON data, you just check everything. You check that you've received a dictionary. You check that there is a property named "docs" and that it is an array. You check that it has at least one element. You get the first element and check that it is a dictionary. You check that the dictionary has a property "title" and a property "edition" and that they are strings and so on.

Fourth, to help keeping your sanity, define an object representing what's in the JSON data, taking a dictionary as an initialiser, and extract everything into that object. So from then on you are in safe NSObject territory.

Fifth, what on earth do you think happens when your users read "Could not parse the JSON feed"? Their poor brains will explode. Error messages are for users, not for programmers.

Comment: I know you can't hear it, but i'm applauding your answer right now